# Options and price is not coming to Configurable product in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, configurable-product, price

We have **configurable product with child product**.

If we are enabling product for Pre-order with all child product. then price is not showing at front end and options are not coming to drop down. 
For more clarity attaching screen-shot.

[image]

**Thanks in advanced**

Comment: options are not showing because it has not getting price. You need to check configurable low price provider. tell me which extension you are using for Pre-order?

Comment: Webkul preorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override below class:

**Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProvider**

```
    <?php

/**
 * Description of AbstractAction
 *
 * @author pramod
 */

namespace Custom\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\LinkedProductSelectBuilderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class LowestPriceOptionsProvider implements \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface {

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * @var LinkedProductSelectBuilderInterface
     */
    private $linkedProductSelectBuilder;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Key is product id. Value is array of prepared linked products
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $linkedProductMap;
    private $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     * @param LinkedProductSelectBuilderInterface $linkedProductSelectBuilder
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
    LinkedProductSelectBuilderInterface $linkedProductSelectBuilder,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resourceConnection;
        $this->linkedProductSelectBuilder = $linkedProductSelectBuilder;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProducts(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product) {
        if (!isset($this->linkedProductMap[$product->getId()])) {
            $productIds = $this->resource->getConnection()->fetchCol(
                    '(' . implode(') UNION (',
                            $this->linkedProductSelectBuilder->build($product->getId())) . ')'
            );

            if (count($productIds) == 0) {

                $configProduct = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());

                $_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
                $childPrice = [];
                foreach ($_children as $child) {
                    $childId = $child->getID();
                    $preorder = $child->getWkPreorder();
                    if ($preorder == 1) {
                        $childPrice[$childId] = $child->getPrice();
                    }
                }

                if($childPrice)
                    $configproductIds = array_keys($childPrice, min($childPrice));
            }
            if (!empty($configproductIds)) {
                $this->linkedProductMap[$product->getId()] = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(
                                ['price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
                        )
                        ->addIdFilter($configproductIds)
                        ->getItems();
            } else {
                $this->linkedProductMap[$product->getId()] = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(
                                ['price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
                        )
                        ->addIdFilter($productIds)
                        ->getItems();
            }
        }
        return $this->linkedProductMap[$product->getId()];
    }

}
```

**app/code/Custom/ConfigurableProduct/etc/di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProvider" type="Custom\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProvider" />
</config>
```

Comment: can you explain what changes you have made in overridden class and why that was needed?

Comment: @Piyush Please,compare original file with this file . You  will get difference. When child product have enabled for pre-order that price was not coming . Without price , variant/options are not populating.